# How create link in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have this problem I want to create a hyperlink in wordpress to the aktu.htm page, which is in the theme's directory and this hyperlink looks like this.

"> CURRENT NEWS

```html
<a class="hiper" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?> "> CURRENT NEWS </a>
```

And when I run into this hyperlink, the icon of no access appears to me
I tried to create a hyperlink

```html
<div id = actu> <a class="hiper" href="<?php echo get_permalink(11) ?> "> CURRENT NEWS </a> </ div>
```

In this case, the target page is loaded over and over again.

Comment: what do you mean over and over

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: @programtreasures  I mean, the start page is loaded.

Comment: do you mean when you click on link the start page gets load?

Comment: the page that is currently loaded.